# How to show time and date in realtime in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, redux, react-hooks

#### Briefing:

Hi, I have created a hook `useDate()` to display current time and date as follows:

```
interface ReturnDate {
  time: string;
  date: string;
  wish: string;
}

export const useDate = (): ReturnDate => {
  const locale = 'en';
  const today = new Date();

  const day = today.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: 'long' });
  const date = `${day}, ${today.getDate()} ${today.toLocaleDateString(locale, { month: 'long' })}\n\n`;

  const hour = today.getHours();
  const wish = `Good ${(hour < 12 && 'Morning') || (hour < 17 && 'Afternoon') || 'Evening'}, `;

  const time = today.toLocaleTimeString(locale, { hour: 'numeric', hour12: true, minute: 'numeric' });

  return {
    date,
    time,
    wish,
  };
};
```

And I'm using it in my **component** below as follows:

```
const ProfileGreetings: FC = () => {
  const { firstName } = useUserDetails();
  const { date, time, wish } = useDate();

  return (
    <div className="greetings-container">
      <h1>
        {wish}
        <PrimaryText text={`${firstName || ''}!`} />
      </h1>

      <div>
        <h3>
          {date}
          <br />
          {time}
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### Date/Time format in app:

Sunday, 2 August

11:54 PM

#### Problem Statement:

Currently what's happening is that the date and time don't update until I **refresh** the page. Is there any way to have all of the following to be updated in **real time**?

I am thinking to use an **interval after every 1 minute** to compute the updated time and date, but don’t really know if that's good idea. Neither do I know how to start with that and how will the interval be **cleared**?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since you can use hooks in custom hooks you can create an interval to update every minute like this:

```
export const useDate = () => {
  const locale = 'en';
  const [today, setDate] = React.useState(new Date()); // Save the current date to be able to trigger an update

  React.useEffect(() => {
      const timer = setInterval(() => { // Creates an interval which will update the current data every minute
      // This will trigger a rerender every component that uses the useDate hook.
      setDate(new Date());
    }, 60 * 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer); // Return a funtion to clear the timer so that it will stop being called on unmount
    }
  }, []);

  const day = today.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: 'long' });
  const date = `${day}, ${today.getDate()} ${today.toLocaleDateString(locale, { month: 'long' })}\n\n`;

  const hour = today.getHours();
  const wish = `Good ${(hour < 12 && 'Morning') || (hour < 17 && 'Afternoon') || 'Evening'}, `;

  const time = today.toLocaleTimeString(locale, { hour: 'numeric', hour12: true, minute: 'numeric' });

  return {
    date,
    time,
    wish,
  };
};
```

Comment: Something to keep in mind when selecting a duration for the interval is what kind of error is tolerable, since a 60 second duration could potentially be up to 60-seconds-minus-1-millisecond off if the component was initiated one millisecond before the true minute switches. This is why many people choose smaller durations, such as 15 seconds or 1 second, since that will ensure the time shown by the component is accurate to +- the duration.

Comment: @jaredgorski that's absolutely correct. Moreover what I was thinking let's say in 30 seconds the minute would increment from 00:30 to 01:00. But as I chose 60 sec as an interval, by the time the minute is updated in my component, the actual realtime minute is 01:30. Thus, an error of 30 seconds.

Comment: @Domino987 the solution is looking absolute promising to me. I was wondering if I could convert the return statement into a **useMemo** hook. Will that be possible?

Comment: Yes I agree with the mentioned time problem and should be adjusted to fit your need. Maybe try some times that work for your. Why would you need a useMemo? And can you accept this answer so other can find the correct solution.

Comment: There is no need to use `setInterval` here. React runs the effect on each update so `setTimeout` could have been used instead. This also means that this will drift slightly. The update won't happen every minute but every minute plus the time it takes to get to re-runing the effect. This may not matter, but to fix it one could instead calculate the time to the next change in minute (`msPerMin - (Date.now() % msPerMin)`) and give that to `setTimeout`.

Comment: No since the useEffect does not have any dependencies, it would not be called multiple times. But calculating the next time might result in an improved timer, that's true.

Answer (score 3):

I have an idea for this.
I will loop on `while` and dynamic sleep with the difference between `currentTime` and rounding in seconds of `currentTime + 1 second`. You can refer to this script.

```js
function getRealTime() {
  const currentTime = Date.now();
  console.log(new Date(Math.round(currentTime / 1000) * 1000), currentTime);
  return (Math.floor(currentTime / 1000) + 1) * 1000 - currentTime;
}

(async function () {
  let reduceTime = 0;
  while (true) {
    reduceTime = getRealTime();
    await sleep(reduceTime);
  }
})()

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Answer (score -8):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
const time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

ReactDom.render(
<>
<p>Today's date is {date}</p>
<p>Today's time is {time}</p>
</>
, 
document.getElementById('root'));

Output

Today's date is 8/14/2020

Today's time is 7:42:01 PM
```

Comment: Rajan, can you explain how will it show updates in realtime?